# Calling an external JS and CSS to my site - What is the risk

Tags: c#, javascript, security

I have trustable partner that I want to allow him to call my Iframe and add a JS/css file path as a parameter and I will call it like that:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="@(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["CustomJs"]))" ></script>
 <link type="text/css"  media="screen" href="@(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["CustomCss"]))" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This is in order to allow him to hook the design and to register some JS hooks.
The partner is trustable and will sign on a document that the use of the JS/css is only for allowed functions that will be called from our side.

The question is, Am I exposing my clients to a dangerous situation from any kind (assuming that the partners are OK).
**it is all under ssl**
What is the security risk.

Thanks

Comment: The code you’ve posted is the document that is loaded inside the frame, right?

Answer (score 2):

The risk is that if the security of your partner is compromised, your system will become insecure as well. Hypothetically, if an attacker somehow adds malicious code to the scripts of your partner, the code may pass on to your system. This is highly related to the cross-site scripting attacks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting .

In order to circumvent this risk, I would recommend implementing a moderated proxy for these JS/CSS files. For example, an ASP.NET Handler (.ashx) that would call the partner's site for original scripts and store them somewhere internally (perhaps in a database), whereas the frame in question takes the scripts and CSS through the usage of handler.  Something like:

```
<script ... src="ModeratedProxy.ashx?partner=abcd&file=efg.js"></script>
```

The handler would notify the site's owner if partner changes scripts, and may even allow pre-moderation of any external files.

Comment: So you've identified a very real risk for the Original Poster (OP).  What about taking a swing at how he can accomplish his goal?  Methods for meeting the same origin policy?  Creating a proxy page of sorts at the original host so the trusted partner can shuffle js/css data through the host?

Comment: @EBarr, thanks for fostering the discussion. In order to circumvent this risk, I would recommend implementing a moderated proxy for these JS/CSS files. For example, an ASP.NET Handler (.ashx) that would call the partner's site for original scripts and store them somewhere internally (perhaps in a database), whereas the frame in question takes the scripts and CSS through the usage of handler (`<script ... src="ModeratedProxy.ashx?partner=abcd&file=efg.js"></script>`). The handler would notify the site's owner if partner changes scripts, and may even allow pre-moderation of any external files.

Answer (score 1):

Since the CSS and JavaScript are embedded into the document in a frame and not directly into your document, the CSS is only applied to the frame’s document.

Whether the frame’s JavaScript can access your document’s DOM is a little more complicated. Because here the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is applied. But unless you and your partner share the same origin, your partner’s JavaScript can’t access you document’s DOM and read data from it or change it.